# Bootstraps extra small size of window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to adapt my website to extra small window sizes with Bootstraps but I didn't found any solution for myself.

[image]

I want to shown one column when the window is too small and keep the left version otherwise. At this point, the code is something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="divLeft">
        <div class="panel panel-success" id="divChart">
            <!-- Some progress bars -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12-offset-6 col-sm-6" id="divMain">
        <h2>Observations</h2>
        <div class="list-group" id="observations">
            <!-- Some panels -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have to do? I tried to add multiple classes to my divs divLeft and divMain but it doesn't work as I want.

Thanks in advance fellas! : D

Answer (score 0):

Each row should always add up to 12 columns.

Have a look at the Bootstrap Docs which tell you about how to work with their grid system:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I'd suggest something like the below for your example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above should result in the two columns displaying one above the other on extra small devices.

Comment: When you say "extra small devices", do you include a desktop with a window like the right one at the original post? Because I tried, but  it doesn't work. : /